# Stackoverflow error in counting the minimum number of coins to make the sum S

Tags: java, recursion, dynamic-programming, stack-overflow

Here I am working on the following problem where we are given n types of coin denominations of values `v(1) > v(2) >  ... > v(n) (all integers)`
 The following code tries to find the minimum number of coins that are required to make a sum-C. Here the C is 100(see main function).When I run the code, error--"java.lang.StackOverflowError" comes. Please help.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Problem2 {

    public static int count=4;
    public static int []v={25,10,5,1}; //Array storing denominations

    private static int findminimum(ArrayList<Integer> v2) {

        int count=v2.get(0);
        for(int i=0;i<v2.size();i++)
        {
            if(count>v2.get(i))
            {
                count=v2.get(i);
            }
        }
        return count;
    }

    public static int countmincoins(int n)
    {
        int t;
        if(n<0)
        {
            t=Integer.MAX_VALUE-100 ;
        }
        if(n==0)
        {
            t= 0;
        }
        else
        {
            ArrayList<Integer> a=new ArrayList<Integer>();          
            for(int i=0;i<v.length;i++)
            {
                int temp=0;
                temp=countmincoins(n-v[i])+1; //Stackoverflow error
                a.add(temp);    
            }   
            t=findminimum(a);

        } 
        return t;   
    }


    public static void main(String args[])
    {

        System.out.println(countmincoins(100)); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Your second `if` should be an `else if`.

Comment: The problem is that the code is not terminating. Please help why is not getting terminated

Comment: @Akshit are you required to use recursion?  A loop would do this much easier.

Comment: if n goes to less than 0, first condition and the last else would also implement and it would never terminate. so like dlev said , ur second if should be an else if

Comment: After keeping my second if as else if it is not terminating...Please tell what might be the problem

Comment: same problem is discussed as a prt of dp tutorial in topcoder http://www.topcoder.com/tc?d1=tutorials&d2=dynProg&module=Static

Answer (score 0):

If your not restricted to using recursion the following would be much simpler:

```
public static int[] denominations = {25,10,5,1};

public static int minimumCoins(int amount){
    int total = 0;
    for(int denomination: denominations){
        while(amount - denomination >= 0){
            amount -= denomination;
            total++;
        }
    }
    return total;
}

public static void main(String args[])
{

    System.out.println(minimumCoins(98)); 
}
```

Comment: How does your code gives the minimum number of coins...It is just returning the total and there is no minimum condition

Comment: @Akshit Are you trying to return simply the least amount of coins to make a total or are you trying to return an itemized version of that count (4 quarters, 2 dimes, 1 nickel)?  If your just looking to say to make 98 cents I need 8 coins, my code does exactly that.

Comment: Akshit In my code the minimum condition is the fact that I iterate through the denominations from largest to smallest.

Comment: Your logic is wrong. You are assuming that by going from largest to smallest you would fetch the minimum number of coins but that is not always correct. Anyways the only problem in my code was that the for the second if I had to replace it with ""if else""

Comment: Can you give me an example of when going from largest to smallest would be wrong?  I would like to see a test case that breaks my code.

Comment: minCoins(25) and denom of {16, 10, 1} .. ur algo would take 10 coins whereas right answer is 7

Answer (score 0):

If you use recursion then you need to reach a condition to terminate the recursion. But in your code I do not seen any termination logic. Thats why, it get to infinite loop and StackOverflowException. In your code you use following code to terminate.

```
if(n==0)
{
    t= 0;
}
```

But here n may not be zero. Becuase `countmincoins(n-v[i])` do not ensure you to n will be 0.

Comment: But I have kept the condition for less than 0 also. Yet it is not terminating

Comment: For that you need to put esle if (n==0).

Comment: less than 0 does not have any effect of termination. It is alone. It is not enclosed with else.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is infinite cause `t` will never be `<0 or ==0` given that the values in the array and the condition `(n - v[i] )+1`,  `v[i]` will always return the same value in every call to the method, therefore infinite recursion.